# Incremental compilation over AST

Tags: programming-languages, compilers

Is incremental compilation ever done based on the AST? That is, the compiler would just regenerate code for the parts of the AST that have changed.

I know that many compilers do incremental compilation on a file-basis, but I don't know about on an AST-basis.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Builder infrastructure actually does this, I believe. You might find this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html) useful.